# How generate the desire output

Tags: c#, json.net

My client api is expecting the below format

```
{
 "foo": [
    { 
      "bar": {
          "firstname": "Jason",
          "lastname": "Long",
          "age" : "34"
       }
    },
    { 
      "bar": {
          "firstname": "John",
          "lastname": "Alex",
          "age": "10"
       }
     }
       "bar": {
          "firstname": "Kelly",
          "lastname": "Aaron",
          "age": "50"
        }
     }
]
}
```

how can i achieve with the above expected json format?
i have declare my object as below but the "bar" always show as array.

```
public class Root
    {
        public List<foo1> foo{ get; set; }
    }

    public class foo1
    {
        public List<bar2> bar{ get; set; }
    }

    public class bar2
    {
        public string firstname {get;set;}
        public string lastname {get;set;}
        public string age {get;set;}
    }
```

the code is written by C#,

the challenge is the "bar" json object, client expected format is an object, but then "bar" has multiple entry.... hence it will shown as [] instead of {}

Answer:
Manage to resolve the issue, i should have declare the bar as single Object instead of List[], because didn't know that i could just add object despite it is not a collection.

Thanks.

Comment: In your JSON, `bar`'s value is an object. In C#, `bar` is a list.

Comment: yea, but client is expecting bar is a repeated/multiple entry object.

Comment: No. It's expecting an array of objects in `foo`, where each object has a single `bar` property, unless you have your JSON incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

If you put your json (after fixing the errors in it) into [Json2Csharp](https://json2csharp.com/) this are the classes that get generated:

```
    public class Bar
    {
        public string firstname { get; set; }
        public string lastname { get; set; }
        public string age { get; set; }
    }

    public class Foo
    {
        public Bar bar { get; set; }
    }

    public class Root
    {
        public List<Foo> foo { get; set; }
    }
```

Which matches your expectation of what Foo and Bar should be. Foo is an object and has a Bar object in it. The root has the List of Foo, aka the array.